# Java is ignoring a boolean evaluation

Tags: java, boolean

```
if (!(portField.getText().equals(""))) {                
    String p = portField.getText();
    CharSequence numbers = "0123456789";

    if (p.contains(numbers)) {

        listener = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(p));

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("Hi there, human.");    
            } finally {
                socket.close(); 
            }
    }} else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only numbers are allowed.");
    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input a port.");
}
```

The problem is: The `JOptionPane` pops up saying "Only numbers are allowed" even when I put numbers in the `portField`. The `CharSequence` and the way I've tested it to allow only numbers to be input, as far as I know, is correct, and Java ignores the whole block and jumps to the `else` clause.

Why is this happening? Should I not use `else` and use `else if` instead?

Comment: What input value are you talking about?

Comment: 9999, 1234, any number, actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`contains` means contains the whole `0123456789`. For example: `"a0123456789b"`

Use `p.matches("[0-9]*");` instead.

Comment: @funforums In OP's code `if (!(portField.getText().equals("")))...`. So that make no difference.

Comment: Okay, but also a string like "abracadabra" matches [0-9]* since * means 0 or more. Since the code he has posted contains an exception case in which he specifies 'Only numbers are allowed', i assume the user can also input other symbols such as letters.

Comment: @funforums "abracadabra" doesn't **matches** "[0-9]*". Just try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: I actually tried with this. It uses PHP preg_match.
http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php
"asd" compared with [0-9]* returns 1.
"asd" compared with [0-9]+ returns 0.

Comment: @funforums Try it in Java. Create a main method and `System.out.println("abracadabra".matches("[0-9]*"));`

Comment: You are right, in java it doesen't pass. I'm wondering which language is right, since the regular expressions should be defined indipendently from the language which implements them. Thinking back to my computation theory books.

Comment: @funforums I don't know PHP preg_match, but I believe it's much more like "find". I think you just used a wrong function.

Comment: @funforums johnchen is right, in Java the whole string is matched when you call `matches()`, even without `^` or `$` at the beginning and end. The question remains if an empty string should match, and if `0` padding is allowed. But that depends more on the use case.